# How to add 2D array in typedef struct based on var1 and var2?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have the following declaration of a typedef struct and a function `newStruct`. The struct contains two ints, var1 and var2. However, I also want to store a 2D int array in the struct, whose dimensions are var1 and var2, i.e. `int arr[var1][var2]` within the struct. How to achieve this?

typedef struct _mystruct *myStruct;

```
typedef struct _mystruct{
     int var1;
     int var2; 
     //I also want to add an array here like so: int arr[var1][var2];
}mystruct; 

myStruct newStruct (int v1, int v2){
    myStruct newSt; 
    newSt = malloc(sizeof(struct _mystruct));

    newSt->var1 = v1; 
    newSt->var2 = v2; 

    return newSt; 
}
```

Comment: Research _flexible array member_ to get close.

Comment: Use `int **arr;` instead of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct _mystruct{
     int var1; // width
     int var2; // height
     int arr[]; // flexible array member
}mystruct; 

myStruct newStruct (int v1, int v2){
    myStruct newSt; 
    size_t arrbytes = sizeof(int) * v1 * v2;
    newSt = malloc(sizeof(struct _mystruct) + arrbytes);

    newSt->var1 = v1; 
    newSt->var2 = v2; 
    memset(&newSt->arr, 0, arrbytes);
    return newSt; 
}
```

Now you can index into it like this:

```
arr[i + j * var1]
```

That is, you allocate the struct with extra space at the end for the 2D array, though it is stored in a way that appears to be 1D.  Then you do the indexing into `arr` using a bit of arithmetic to turn 2D (i,j) into a 1D coordinate.